# PHP tags aren't recognized when placed like '<?'

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple CakePHP application and in my Views, I dynamically set the title for each view:

```
<? $this->viewVars['title_for_layout'] = 'Wicked Awesome Title' ?>
```

However on one of my machines, the code is not run but instead outputted to the browser windows as if it weren't recognized PHP code.

```
<!-- Actual output in the browser window. -->    
viewVars['title_for_layout'] = 'Wicked Awesome Title' ?>
```

If I place the proper `<?php` tag, everything runs fine, but that is not the default way CakePHP recommends.

Why does it work on one machine, but not in the other?

Comment: Because they're configured differently - I believe that the default configuration now is only to use the full tags.

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: "but that is not the default way CakePHP recommends" where did you read that? you are wrong about that. you should use <?php instead of <? (so your machines are right^^)

Comment: Double-check your configuration using `phpinfo()`. One of your machines doesn't have `short_open_tags` turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your machines does not have [`short_open_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled in its configuration.